# How do I prove that the -1 constant can be ignored in this summation for a limit?

Tags: limits, summation

I effectively want to show that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=an}^{n} \frac{1}{i-1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=an}^{n} \frac{1}{i}$$

I know that $$\frac{1}{n-1} < \frac{1}{i-1} < \frac{1}{an-1}$$ Also $0 < a < 1$.

I first split the first summation up into two separate sums like so:

$$\sum_{i=an}^{n} \frac{1}{i-1} = \sum_{i=an}^{n} \frac{1}{i} + \sum_{i=an}^{n} \frac{1}{i^2}$$

So I guess I have to show the second summation $\to$ 0 as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: As $an$ need not be an integer, the summation should be over $i\geq an$. The limit is $\log 1/a$, is it not?

Comment: Yes, that is the final limit! But I am curious about this particular step and why we are able to ignore the -1 constant.

Comment: because the sum is "almost equal" to the integral $\int_{an}^n\frac{dx}{x}$, give or take one term that tends to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left\{\sum_{i\ge an}^{n} \frac{1}{i-1} - \sum_{i\ge an}^{n} \frac{1}{i}\right\}=\frac1{\lceil an-1\rceil}-\frac1{n}$$  This difference goes to $0$.

Comment: Thanks. I like this explanation a lot. Do you know where I can find why those summations equal those fractions? As I don't understand how you've moved from summation to fractions.

Comment: If you just wrote out the sums in full, you'd see that all the terms cancel, other than those two. It is a telescoping series (you can google that). $$\require{cancel}\sum_{i\ge an}^n\left(\frac1{i-1}-\frac1i\right)=\left(\frac1{\lceil an-1\rceil}+\cancel{\frac1{\lceil an\rceil}}+\cancel{\frac1{\lceil an+1\rceil}}+\cdots+\cancel{\frac1{n-2}}-\cancel{\frac1{n-1}}\right)-\left(\cancel{\frac1{\lceil an\rceil}}+\cancel{\frac1{\lceil an+1\rceil}}+\cdots+\cancel{\frac1{n-1}}+\frac1n\right)$$

Comment: Very cool. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\sum_{i=n}^{m} \frac{1}{i-1} = \sum_{i=n-1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{i}$$
So you gain one term at one end and lose one at the other.